# Doctrine2 Paginator skip offset in phpunit test

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pagination, phpunit

Doctrine2 paginator can have offset and limit as follows:

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                   ->setFirstResult(0)
                   ->setMaxResults(100);

$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);
```

It works fine, however same situation as unit tested in phpunit fails to set offset,
i tried `$query->getResult` instead of Paginator and offset was applied,
in both cases the sql has the offset, but paginator just starts from the beginning

Comment: Could you show the code you use for this failing test ?

Comment: `$selector->setFirstResult($offset);
$selector->setMaxResults($limit);
$paginator = new Paginator($selector->getQuery()->setParameters($parameters), $fetchJoinCollection = true);
return $paginator;`
this is a method that select and i call it through my test case,
it passes if i replaced paginator line by `$selector->getQuery()-getResult()` ,currently it neglects limit and offset whatever offset is less than returned entries count or more,

Comment: It would be better to show the complete test class. You can edit your original post to add more code, it will be more readable. Do you use the same database for your tests and dev ?